# My websites can't be reached

Tags: linux, centos5

I managing a VPS that has some domains running on it. I made a minor changes to the server through plesk control panel like some changes to the IP address of the server. Now i am only the person how can reach any website hosted on that server.

the main domain name that worked as the name-server of the whole server is:

www.oes-server.com

How could i debug the problem and handle it?

Comment: DNS is pointing to 184.168.80.199=www.oes-server.com

Comment: Server has 2 Ip address 184.168.125.16, 184.168.80.199 and the host-name of this domain was pointed to 184.168.80.199 since half an hour and i was changed it to 184.168.125.16 and i think it doesn't take effect till now

Comment: Make sure your dns has been updated to reflect the ip change. Same goes for other domains

Comment: how to ensure that the DNS updated successfully, also do you mean the DNS of the oes-server.com

Comment: whats another domain that cannot be reached?

Comment: http://khutowat.ly/, http://www.oes-edu.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10493/discussion-between-splaer-and-ahmedsaber111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check other domain names to make sure they are pointing to the right dns server if you made an IP change on the vps. DNS can take awhile to update externally. 24-48 hours in some instances. Domain name lookup services or nslookup are your friend in this scenario.

Also make sure your virtualhosts in apache are listening on the right IP